# Calculating Diversity Indices at a Specific Taxonomic Level Using Richness Tables without OTU Association Information

Tags: diversity

I have a question concerning the calculation of indices, such as the Shannon index, Inverse Simpson, etc., at a specific taxonomic level (e.g., family level) using a richness table of that particular level. For instance, if we have a count table where rows represent subjects and columns represent families, how can we derive a Shannon index table with rows as subjects and columns as families?

To my knowledge, I only know the formula to calculate indices based on OTUs belonging to the family. However, my current dataset lacks information on indicating which OTU belongs to which family.

Could anyone please guide me on this issue? Or, if you have any paper about this, could you share it with me?